# Can I run steps in team city before team city does an update from my repository?

Tags: svn, build, build-process, teamcity

been thinking about wanting to do some custom things before team city does any sort of svn updates or modifications checks.

Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

Yes you can do. The first thing probably you may have to do is to stop the automatic checkout by editing the VCS Settings under Build Configurations

[image]

But leave the build triggering mechanism unaltered. After that, do your customized things as the first step in the build step. Then do a checkout manually using another shell script. Then continue with your build. This will require you adding more steps in the build steps.

[image]

Comment: thanks for the response. do you have a sample of what a command line checkout would look like?

Comment: @towpse : sure, can you tell me which Operating system it is? Linux or Mac or Windows

Comment: looks like it would look something like C:\Program Files\SubversionDir\bin\svn.exe update D:\MyProjectDir\MySvnRootDir\

Comment: @towpse : windows you would typically want to write a batch file and put in commands specific to them (since i've mostly worked in linux machines)

Answer (score 1):

Old question, but another, probably easier way to do this is to add another build configuration to your project where you could add your scripts as build steps and then make this new configuration a snapshot dependency of your existing configuration.

Note that you can make this configuration run on the same build agent.